# sql update is not working

Tags: c#, sql, connection

I'm having a problem. I want to update the table but the code I'm using is not working can - someone explain why?

```
public void ChangeInfo(string Newname, string NewFullname, string NewEmail)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("MyconnectionString");
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Users] SET [UserName]='" + Newname + "', [Fullname]='" + NewFullname + "', [Email]='" + NewEmail + "' WHERE [ID]='" + this.ID + "'", con);
    con.Open();

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

**Note: All the column names are written correctly and the ID is correct too.**

Comment: please explain "not working" in detail.

Comment: Not without any info. What is the value of 'ID", does the record actually exist in the database, are you really trying to set a new username or are you possibly setting the same value? Have you opened a transaction outside the code you posted? Are you connecting to the correct database? If you execute the same statement using SSMS, do you get any results?

Comment: dude use parameters.  That's not only ugly, it's super destroyable

Comment: BTW string concatenation IS the root of all SQL statement evil. Use parameterized queries, it's actually easier

Comment: the value of ID is 999999999, "not working" means the table is not updated

Comment: And is there any record with that ID in the table? Have you opened a transaction you forgot to close?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes of course

Comment: Do you get any error and what do they say?

Comment: please try to run SQL profiler, capture SQL statement and run it from SQL management studio. There is nothing wrong with code as i can see. The only one strange thing is that you've enclosed ID value using ' and it is passed as string. Do you really have varchar ID in the database? I suppose that there is something on the DB side or you have not set ID value properly. Do you have some trigger instead of update on the table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you should wrap your `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` in `using` to dispose properly.  Then **NEVER** use string concatenation in SQL as it leaves you open to SQL Injection attacks.

```
    public void ChangeInfo(string Newname, string NewFullname, string NewEmail)
    {
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("MyconnectionString"))
        using (
            SqlCommand command =
                new SqlCommand(
                    "UPDATE [Users] SET [UserName] = @UserName, [Fullname] = @NewFullName, [Email] = @NewWmail WHERE [ID] = @Id",
                    con))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Newname);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewFullName", NewFullname);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewMail", NewEmail);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id", this.ID);

            con.Open();

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

That being said, you either have a bad Connection string (you have not shown us the syntax) or you had syntax error in your query which should be cleared up by my example.

If you want further explanation you will need to define `It doesn't work` and provide the error you are getting.

Comment: +1; good explanation. Based on OP's updates, though, he's not getting any exceptions, just a failure of updating. Perhaps the record he is trying to update really doesn't exist or the ID he's using is wrong. That's all I can think of.

Comment: thank you that worked, but I still don't understand why that thing happened?

Comment: No problem, please accept the answer if it worked for you.  As to *why*, I'm not sure... possibly one of your values had an `'` in it?  Using paramaterized queries almost always gets rid of syntax errors, and makes your code safer at the same time.  Win Win.

Comment: Competitive upvoting? :) +1

Answer (score -1):

Even though i have no clear idea. With the intention to help. I guess MyconnectionString is your variable with the connection string. If it is a variable with the connection string please remove the quotes because its a variable. Please reply if that is the error. :)